# Best way to print key-value pairs: table, array or matrix?

Tags: tables, automation, columns

I have a series of values that need to be printed row-wise in multiple columns. (These values, held as `\def` variables, are generated programatically and some of them can be empty strings.)

The problem is how to avoid the empty cells and have the next cell automatically take the previous cell place if its empty. For example, I have these non-empty values: `Author`, `Composer`, `Publisher`, `Year` to be arranged in 3 columns as:

```
Author    Composer    Publisher

Year
```

That is in two rows. If we add one more entry, it should go to next cell after `Year`.

However, if the Publisher is empty then Year should automatically come to the first row as:

```
Author    Composer    Year
```

I have `\Author`, `\Composer`, `\Publisher`, `\Year` and so on list of variables that need to be arranged as this. I just would like to write something like:

```
\SomeEnvironment{\Author, \Composer, \Publisher, \Year, \something so on}
```

and let the environment figure out automatically to remove the empty ones and let the next ones flow.

How to achieve this?

PS: For those curios, this is part of [CarMusTy](http://carmusty.sourceforge.net): Carnatic Music Typesetting Environment project.

Comment: I just wonder why you must end up with control sequences and not `\SomeEnvironment{Author, Composer, Publisher, Year, something, somethingelse, and on}`.

Comment: Control sequences for multiple reasons (hopefully sensible ones): 1. These are generated programatically and are supplied as arguments for other packages - so I have no control over skipping some arguments. 2. Need to add indices over these values and control sequence offers me to do that easily be changing the sequence definition 3. for checking if empty etc.. its easy to do it with control sequences. Originally tried with 'directly placing' the values in the env commands, but control squences are more powerful to manipulate them as macros etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure whether you wanted plain or latex, the macros should work with both, although this is a plain document

```
\def\SomeEnvironment#1{%
  \par\noindent
  \xSomeEnvironment #1\relax}

\def\xSomeEnvironment#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
  \hfill
  \else
  \ifx\empty#1%
  \else
   \hbox to 0.3333\hsize{#1\hfill}\hfil
  \fi
  \expandafter\xSomeEnvironment 
  \fi}

\def\Author{Author}
\def\Composer{Composer}
\def\Publisher{}
\def\Year{Year}
\def\something{something}
\def\somethingelse{somethingelse}

\SomeEnvironment{\Author \Composer \Publisher \Year \something \somethingelse} 

\bye
```

[image]

This loops by inspecting each token, if it is `\relax` it stops, if it has teh same definition as `\empty` it skips that token, otherwise it sets the content in a box of with 1/3 of the textwidth (0.333330). So no explicit line breaking or alignment points are needed, when the paragraph is broken up into lines in the usual way, the only place that breaks can happen is every third entry as boxes never break. To get more columns just change the 0.33333 eg 0.25 would give you four columns.

**EDIT:**

Your real case was a bit more complicated as rather than just a single token you either wanted a brace group or `\var` followed by a brace group, and your definitions are not then empty but defined to be `\relax` due to `\csname` weirdness.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\DefVar}[2]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\SetVar}[2]{\ifcsname #1\endcsname
                         \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname{#2}
                         \else \DefVar{#1}{#2} \fi}
\newcommand{\Var}{\var}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\SomeEnvironment#1{%
  \par\noindent
  \xSomeEnvironment #1\relax}

\def\xSomeEnvironment#1{%
  \ifx\var#1\relax
  \expandafter\xxxSomeEnvironment
  \else
  \ifx\relax#1\relax
  \hfill
  \else
  \def\tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\xxSomeEnvironment
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tempa
  \fi
  \fi}

\def\xxSomeEnvironment#1{%
  \hbox to 0.3333\hsize{#1\hfill}\hfil
  \expandafter\xSomeEnvironment 
  }

\def\xxxSomeEnvironment#1{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempa\csname#1\endcsname
  \ifx\relax\tempa
  \expandafter\xSomeEnvironment 
  \else
  \expandafter\xxSomeEnvironment\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
  \fi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\def\index[#1]#2{}




% Below attributes are programatically set by user in the CarMusTy Document
% 
% Note that these could be unicode values in real documents, hence we need these as \csname in the \var{} definitions
%
% Als note that if a variable is not set any value, such as Song2Composer below, it will not be defined (which is fine because the \var{} allows it to be \relax)
%  For testing these are commented out below, making them undefined.
%
\DefVar{BookTOC}{Book Title}
\DefVar{BookTitle}{Book Title}
\DefVar{BookSubTitle}{Sub Title}
\DefVar{BookAuthor}{Book Author}
\DefVar{BookPublisher}{Book Publisher}
\DefVar{BookYear}{Book Year}
\DefVar{Song1Title}{Song Title1}
\DefVar{Song1Author}{Author1\index[Author]{Author1!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song1Composer}{Composer1\index[Composer]{Composer1!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song1Singers}{Singers1\index[Singers]{Singers1!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song1Movie}{Movie1\index[Movie]{Movie1!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song1Year}{Year1}
\DefVar{Song1Raga}{RAGAVARDHINI\index[Raga]{RAGAVARDHINI!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song1Tala}{tripuTa\index[Tala]{tripuTa!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song1Verse1Title}{Verse}
\DefVar{Song1Verse2Title}{Verse}
\DefVar{Song2Title}{Song Title2}
\DefVar{Song2Author}{Author2\index[Author]{Author2!\var{SongTitle}}}
%\DefVar{Song2Composer}{Composer1\index[Composer]{Composer1!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song2Singers}{Singers1\index[Singers]{Singers1!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song2Movie}{Movie2\index[Movie]{Movie2!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song2Year}{Year2}
\DefVar{Song2Raga}{Raga2\index[Raga]{Raga2!\var{SongTitle}}}
%\DefVar{Song2Tala}{Tala2\index[Tala]{Tala2!\var{SongTitle}}}
\DefVar{Song2Verse1Title}{Verse}
\DefVar{Song2Verse2Title}{Verse}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% Lets Print them

\section*{}
{\huge{Song Title}}
\SomeEnvironment{{Author} {Composer} {Singers} {Movie} {Year} }

% Uncomment the below lines to see the error
\section*{}
{\huge\var{Song1Title}}
\SomeEnvironment{\var{Song1Author} \var{Song1Composer} \var{Song1Singers} \var{Song1Movie} \var{Song1Year}} % << - Uncomment this line to see the error

\section*{}
{\huge\var{Song2Title}}
\SomeEnvironment{\var{Song1Author} \var{Song1Composer} \var{Song1Singers} \var{Song1Movie} \var{Song1Year}}  % << - Uncomment this line to see the error

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David ...this is very close - Since my \Author etc. definitions are little bit complex  (they allow unicode characters, hence \csname'd, and allow indexes).  So, when I used this environment on them, encountering few compiler errors, and also the empty cell space is not going away. For your convenience, I have extracted portions and created MWE http://gpalem.web.officelive.com/Test.tex Could you please check it  ? The issue is, for each song there are authors, composer etc. so the variable names are held as Song1Author1 etc. which are allowed only as \csname - so we have this \var{}

Comment: Also, could you please give some info on how this is created? I see that you are trying to compare with \relax and \empty etc.. and then use \hbox to print - but I could not get how is it going to next row and how to tweak number of columns, row height etc.. If you can share 'behind the scenes' info I can learn to create my own or tune it. Thx.

Comment: oh your real example has `\var{Song1Year}` not \Song1Year so it will fail as my loop grabs one toen at a time however that is easy to fix, to either grab two tokens (`\var` and the brace group) or probably more simply just define `\var` locally to do the right thing, then no loop is needed at all. Will send something later once ive caught up with day job.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Please is there any reason why you didn't use `\def` in `\Defvar`? That will save the need for `\SetVar` and `\renewcommand`. Redefinition takes place anyway. I would have used a key-value system in place of the definitions. Also why not simply do `\let\Var\var` in place of `\newcommand\Var{var}`?

Comment: @AhmedMusa all that code was from the OP's MWE I thought it would be better to leave that as is and supply the requested code to fit. Your comments are good ones though should the OP wish to look at revising the definition constructs.

Comment: @AhmedMusa Yes, they are from MWE and not David's. Your \let suggestion seems to be good - I can try it. As for \DefVar and \SetVar, they are needed in my case for the CarMusTy project. Their purpose is: This whole tex file is generated programatically and lets users to override the default values (through some place holder scripts in the program). \DefVar lets the command names be like 'Song1Author' (note the number 1 in the command name) in a simple to use way. The \SetVar lets users override the values in a easy way. Users are not really tex-aware in this case - so they need simple sintax

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your solution is perfectly working fine. I am not sure I could have figured out the solution myself, what with all those \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter and \tempa definitions. I will try to learn about them. Marking this as answer, as it fully addresses the question raised. I will take care of tuning it for my further needs. Thank you much for your time.

Comment: 3 `\expandafter` in a row doesn't really count as "all those" (once you get to 31 in a row you need to start wonder if you're doing it right:-) One notable benefit of the LaTeX3 xparse argument syntax is that such explicit expansion tricks are largely hidden and each command just specifies if its arguments are to be expanded before the call so no `\expandafter` are needed to expand re-arrange the expansion order. (Well they are needed of course but hidden in the underlying LaTeX kernel code).

Comment: Thanks David. Just a quick question: What is the significance of the number 3 in this case for having 3 \expandafter ?? Is it something like 'recursion depth' for explanding the commands recursively or ..?

Comment: maybe that ought be a separate question, but while other uses are required sometimes, most uses of `\expandafter` have `2^n-1` so 1,3,7,15,31 (I think I really did use 15 in real code once, can't find it now:-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, defying David Carlisle, the patent holder of key-value system, I decided to go key-value syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyreader}[2012/01/14]
\usepackage{catoptions}[2011/12/17]
% Load geometry to enlarge the print area:
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\new@def*\var#1{\usename{carm@#1}}
\newletcs\Var\var
\def\Arrange#1{\par\noindent\xArrange#1\@nnil}
\def\xArrange#1{%
  \expandafter\ifcseqTF\@car#1\@nil\var{%
    \xxArrange
  }{%
    \expandafter\ifcseqTF\@car#1\@nil\@nnil{%
      \hfill
    }{%
      \hb@xt@\dimexpr\carm@alignment{#1\hfill}\hfil
      \xArrange
    }%
  }%
}
\def\xxArrange#1{%
  \ifcsndefFT{carm@\cpttrimspaces{#1}}{}{%
    \hb@xt@\dimexpr\carm@alignment{\@nameuse{carm@\cpttrimspaces{#1}}\hfill}\hfil
  }%
  \xArrange
}
% I don't want us to redefine \index, which is a LaTeX command. Hence
% I use \iindex instead. I assume that \iindex has one optional argument.
\new@def*\iindex{\cpt@testopt\iindex@a{}} % no \robust@def here!
\new@def*\iindex@a[#1]#2{}

\robust@def*\carm@getcallback#1#2{%
  \def\@tempa##1#1##2\carm@nil{%
    \edef\call@back{\cpttrimspaces{##2}}%
    \carm@split##1==\carm@nil
  }%
  \@tempa#2\carm@nil
}
\robust@def*\carm@split#1=#2=#3\carm@nil{%
  \edef\@tempa{\cpttrimspaces{#1}}%
  \edef\@tempb{\cpttrimspaces{#2}}%
  \edef\key@values{\csliststack,\key@values
    \expandcsonce\@tempa=\expandcsonce\@tempb}%
  \ifcsndefFT{CARM@carmusty@\@tempa}{}{%
    \if@carmst
      \@latex@error{CarMusty key '\@tempa' redefined}\@ehc
    \else
      \@latex@warning@no@line{CarMusty key '\@tempa' redefined}%
    \fi
  }%
  \cptexpandsecond{\define@cmdkey[CARM]{carmusty}[carm@]}%
    {{\expandcsonce\@tempa}[{\expandcsonce\@tempb}]%
    {\expandcsonce\call@back}}%
}
\robust@def*\carmustykeys{\cpt@teststopt\carmustykeys@a{define}}
\robust@def*\carmustykeys@a[#1]{%
  \let\if@carmst\ifcpt@st
  \begingroup
  \endlinechar\m@ne
  \xifstrcmpTF{\cpttrimspaces{#1}}{define}{%
    \definecarmustykeys
  }{%
    \xifstrcmpTF{\cpttrimspaces{#1}}{set}{%
      \setcarmustykeys
    }{%
      \@latex@error{Unknown carmusty action '\detokenize{#1}'}\@ehc
    }%
  }%
}
\robust@def*\definecarmustykeys#1{%
  \endgroup
  \def\key@values{}%
  \cptdocommalist{#1}{%
    \ifinsetTF{.code=}{##1}{%
      \carm@getcallback{.code=}{##1}%
    }{%
      \ifinsetTF{.code =}{##1}{%
        \carm@getcallback{.code =}{##1}%
      }{%
        \carm@getcallback{.code=}{##1.code=}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \cptexpandargonce{\krdsetkeys[CARM]{carmusty}}\key@values
}
\robust@def*\setcarmustykeys#1{%
  \endgroup
  \cptexpandsecond\krdsetkeys{\if@carmst*\fi}[CARM]{carmusty}{#1}%
}

% When defining keys, the star (*) variant of \carmustykeys will
% raise an error when an existing key is being redefined.

% When setting keys, the star (*) variant of \carmustykeys will use
% the star variant of \setkeys. See the documentation of 'keyreader'
% or 'xkeyval' to see the meaning of the starred form of \setkeys.
% Actually, we don't use \setkeys but the more robust \krdsetkeys.

% Examples:
\carmustykeys*[define]{%
  keya = .3333\hsize .code = \def\x##1{#1##1},
  % Uncomment the following line to get an error (keya is being redefined):
  % keya = default of keya .code = \def\result{generate error}
}
\carmustykeys*[set]{%
  keya = valuea
}

% Real business:
\carmustykeys{%
  alignment = .3333\hsize,
  BookTOC = Book Title,
  BookTOC = Book Title, % redefined - see log file for warning
  BookTitle = Book Title,
  BookSubTitle = Sub Title,
  BookAuthor = Book Author,
  BookPublisher = Book Publisher,
  BookYear = Book Year,
  Song1Title = Song Title1,
  Song1Author = Author1\iindex[Author]{Author1!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song1Composer = Composer1\iindex[Composer]{Composer1!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song1Singers = Singers1\iindex[Singers]{Singers1!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song1Movie = Movie1\iindex[Movie]{Movie1!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song1Year = Year1,
  Song1Raga = RAGAVARDHINI\iindex[Raga]{RAGAVARDHINI!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song1Tala = tripuTa\iindex[Tala]{tripuTa!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song1Verse1Title = Verse,
  Song1Verse2Title = Verse,
  Song2Title = Song Title2,
  Song2Author = Author2\iindex[Author]{Author2!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song2Composer = Composer1\iindex[Composer]{Composer1!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song2Singers = Singers1\iindex[Singers]{Singers1!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song2Movie = Movie2\iindex[Movie]{Movie2!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song2Year = Year2,
  Song2Raga = Raga2\iindex[Raga]{Raga2!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song2Tala = Tala2\iindex[Tala]{Tala2!\var{SongTitle}},
  Song2Verse1Title = Verse,
  Song2Verse2Title = Verse,
}
\makeatother

% If needed, you can add new keys by doing:
% \carmustykeys[define]{key1=value1,<...>,key2=value2}

% To change the alignment, you can do:
% \carmustykeys[set]{alignment=<some value>}

% Let's print them:
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\carmustykeys[set]{alignment=.1333\hsize}

\textbf{Song Title}
\Arrange{{Author} {Composer} {Singers} {Movie} {Year} }

\par\medskip
\textbf{\var{Song1Title}}
\Arrange{\var{Song1Author} \var{Song1Composer} \var{Song1Singers}
  \var{Song1Movie} \var{Song1Year} \var{Song1Verse2Title}}

\par\medskip
\textbf{\var{Song2Title}}
\Arrange{\var{Song1Author} \var{Song1Composer} \var{Song1Singers}
  \var{Song1Movie} \var{Song1Year}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow...nice and tidy all keys in one place - I would really like to use this - but I am not able to understand how this is being achieved. I tried compiling on latex2, but got some errors (I cannot use L3 for this project as it has unicode glyph problems). Does this approach support unicode values? For example, Author1, Movie1 etc. could be unicode glyphs.

Comment: This is all LaTeX2e and not LaTeX3. I don't foresee any problem with unicode. Can you please post examples of the errors you said you have encountered? Before posting my solution I generated several trial outputs. I will post a sample output in a moment.

Comment: My bad..sorry, its compiling fine and giving the output. Though I could not understand how it works - but its another great way of doing this. Thanks for taking time on this and presenting the solution